# python seqdiag file is big and can't be openned in other computer?

Tags: python, png, appdata

I have used seqdiag to generate sequence diagram, and it generates 3MB png file. It sounds great, right? But something wrong when I open it. When I open the file, appdata/local/temp has gained 3GB, and generates big files named ~PI*.tmp. After I send the png file to others, they can't open the file in their computer. What is the root cause and how I can send this kind of file to others?

Comment: are you opening the file using windows explorer or programatically?

Comment: I open the file with windows photo viewer

Comment: What are the image dimensions (width, height)?  Some viewers (e.g., firefox) impose limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is file size. I split the file into ten parts, and each file can be opened. Thx all answers.